# Creating a login screen to link up to a form in an iOS app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, authentication

I wish to create a login screen which only shows in the app once and basically it would just have a "Username" and Password" field. When the "Login" button is pressed, I would like the data from the "Username" and "Password" fields to be input into a form and then submit the data to an action (such as "/index.phtml?d=187209&destination_page=187224").

How can I do this, what's the best way of doing it? Seen all the questions on SO but none of them are what I need...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very broad question and will likely be voted down. But generally speaking you need to look at [this](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) and [this](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use). It's a very easy framework to incorporate into your code. I highly recommend it.

Comment: is there an easier way though as this seems a bit of a long winded way of doing it? :)

Comment: This is about easy as it gets. There maybe some NSURL functions you can use, but they have a bad reputation. Honestly, the ASIHTTP framework is pretty simple to use.

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a go :) are there any step by step tutorials out there - apart from on their site as they aren't very detailed?